# Javascript - How to use replace() function properly

Tags: javascript

I am willing to do the following:

I have :

```
    var distance1 = "5.5 Km";
    var distance2 = "5,5 Km";
    //The below works as expected and returns 5.5
    var finalDistance = distance1.replace( /[^\d\.]*/g, '');

    //However the below doesn't and print 55 instead
    distance2.replace( /[^\d\.]*/g, '');

    //I've tried the below too and it throws 5,5. But I want 5.5
    distance2.replace( /[^\d\.\,]*/g, '');
```

Comment: What is the result you are expecting and what do you mean by throws and prints? Do you mean returns?

Comment: @AliSomay in `distance2` I want to see `5.5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, replace all occurences of `,` with `.`, then replace non-digit characters (except `.`) with `''`:

```
distance2 = distance2.replace( /,/g, '.').replace(/[^\d\.]+/g, '');
```

where:

```
/,/g : matches all commas ',' that will be replaced by '.'
/[^\d\.]+ : matches any sequence of non-digit and non-dot ('.') characters that will be removed (replaced by the empty string '').
```

The first replace transform `"5,55 KM"` to `"5.55 KM"` then the second transform the latter to `"5.55"`.

**Note:** if you only have one comma, or only interested in the first encountered one, then you could use: `replace(',', '.')` instead of `replace(/,/g, '.')`.

If you are using only the float representation, you could use `parseFloat` instead of the second `replace`:

```
var number = parseFloat(distance2.replace(/,/g, '.'));
```

Comment: It works, but I would really appreciate if you can explain more what's inside the parenthesis, i.e `replace( /,/g, '.')` and `replace( /[^\d\.]+/g, '')`

Comment: @Folky.H You should do some regex tutorials if you want to understand what's going on there. It's a bit complicated if you don't know regex. Alternatively you could just use strings for the first parameter as described in my answer :P

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

`replace` works by saying "find this string and replace with this string". The first parameter is what you want to find, the second is what to replace it with. So in your code you're replacing the `,` with nothing:

```
distance2.replace( /[^\d\.]*/g, '');
```

It also doesn't edit the string "in-place", so you need to assign the `distance2` variable to the return value. Also, for a simple job like this you don't need to use regex. You can just input a string as the first parameter and `replace` will find all matches for that. This is how I would do this:

```
distance2 = distance2.replace(',', '.');
```

---

Further reading:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score -1):

you need to reassign the replace value to the variable.

i.e.

```
distance2 = distance2.replace( /[^\d\.]*/g, '');
```

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that the `,` is being replaced with nothing.